# Swift: How to check for partial occurrence of keywords in a string

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to check if a string contains atleast two or 50% of a set of keywords.

I currently run a check for string that contains all the keywords

```
 var keywords = ["house","floor", "cleaner"] 
 let string = "SWIFFER WETJET FLOOR CLEANER HOUSE SOLUTION REFILL, LAVENDER, 1 CT"
 let string2 = "FABULOSO ALL PURPOSE CLEANER, LAVENDER - 169 FL OZ"

 let success = !keywords.contains(where: { !generatedString.contains($0) })
```

This works and returns true if all the keywords are in a string. Now I want to just check for atleast two or 50% of the keywords in the string.

so success will return true for string2 too.
How can I implement a check for atleast two or 50% of the keywords in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter and count keywords which are contained within the string.

```
  let count = keywords.filter { generatedString.contains($0) }.count
```

Then compare count to two or 50% or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
let keywordsCount = keywords.filter({ string.lowercased().contains($0.lowercased()) }).count

if keywordsCount >= keywords.count / 2 {
    print("Success")
} else {
    print("Failure")
}
```